# Identify part with handle, rod and loop

Tags: part-identification

I have been trying to figure out this part for 2 days now,  using every descriptor I can think of. There is no visible part number, just the LEGO stamp and 2-01. Please help!
[image]

Comment: I can remember those were used in old sets I played with as a kid (back in the '90s), mostly as kind of "blasters" with a transparent piece attached to the pin or the 1-pin part.

Comment: It was used in 42 sets form 1996-2014.  About half of those seem to be in the 96-97 timeframe, fitting kopaka's memory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is the [Space Scanner Tool 30035](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30035).

[image: 30035 image]

Comment: You are awesome, thank you!!!